# Why are the angle brackets before the return type omitted sometimes from the definition of a generic method

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

I was reading Effective Java chapter 5 about generics, in particular the items on preferring generic methods. I noticed that sometimes the  type parameter(between angle brackets) in the method declaration before the return type is sometimes omitted. There are many cases like that, but for example on page 135 of the second edition:

```
public void popAll(Collection<E> dst) {
while (!isEmpty())
dst.add(pop());
}
```

On the other hand, I have seen similar generic methods with the declaration

```
public <E> void ...
```

Is the first one a typo? If not when can I omit the brackets from the declaration?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this was marked as a duplicate. The purported dupe is a completely different question.

Comment: Since I can't post a legitimate answer, I'll answer with a comment: I believe the difference is that in the first case the whole class is declared generic whereas in the second case only the method is generic.

Comment: Voted to reopen too.  I couldn't figure it out from the other question.  The seem related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`E` is a *type variable* -- it stands in for some other type, like `String` or `Integer`.  So just as you can't understand `dst.add(pop())` without knowing where and how `dst` was defined, you can't understand a method declaration like `popAll(Collection<E> dst)` without knowing where and how the type variable `E` is defined.  In the case of `popAll`, the type variable `E` is defined at the class level: `Stack<E>`: it's the type of the elements in the stack.  You'll often even see it javadoc'd:

```
/**A Stack of elements
  *
  *@param E The type of elements in the stack */
public class Stack<E>{
    public void popAll(Collection<E> dst){ ... }
}
```

On the other hand, when you see a method declaration like `public <E> void ...`, the type variable `E` is being **declared** (not **referenced** from some enclosing scope like the enclosing class).  In fact most times when you see a method with its own type variable, it's a static method, so there is no enclosing instance of the class to establish the value of `E`.

In both cases, what is the `E` type variable doing?  It's telling us how two different types have to relate to each other.  In `popAll`, it's telling us that the element type of the collection you want to put the popped elements into has to match the element type of the stack you're popping them from.

Similarly, take the example from page 136:

```
public class ListUtils{
    public static <E> E reduce(List<E> list, Function<E> f, E initVal);
}
```

Here, the `E` type variable tells us that the element type of `list` has to match the argument type of `f` and the type of `initVal`.  The surrounding class does not define `E` for us, it's only meaningful in the scope of the `reduce` method declaration.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that in the first case the whole class is declared generic whereas in the second case only the method is generic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is... it's not. A "generic method" is *defined* to be one that declares type variables before the return type:

> A method is *generic* if it declares one or more type variables. ([JLS 8.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4))

Therefore, `popAll` is not a "generic method".

Since the method does not declare the type parameter `E`, it must be defined in an enclosing scope; almost certainly by the class (a "generic class") that contains the method.